# Is if(x < Infinity) the best way to check if x is not NaN and can be coerced to a Number?

Tags: javascript

I know NaN is not less than Infinity. I have tested many strings, and it seems that strings whom can be coerced to a Number type are less than infinity, while those who cannot are not. Is this a solid method to check if a variable "can" be of the number type?

Comment: use `isNan()` method instead.

Comment: Your exact goal isn't clear enough but it can probably be covered with a more standard test.

Comment: When you say, "can be coerced to a number" remember that _almost_ anything in JavaScript can; it's weakly typed after all.  What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried using Infinity. But I think [isNaN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) does just what you want!

Comment: According to the question, this answer is plain wrong because it doesn't work for `"Infinity"`. It's still useful and relevant because most people don't usually care for infinities or don't see them as numbers. The right solution to use is all about the specific requirement.

Answer (score 4):

No, because

```
''<Infinity
```

gives `true`

Answer (score 3):

If you want neither NaN nor Infinity, try `isFinite`:

```
$ node
> isFinite(Infinity)
false  
> isFinite(NaN)
false
> isFinite(3E100)
true
```

But remember that in JavaScript, almost anything can be coerced to a number.

```
false => 0
true => 1
null => 0
"3" => 3
```

and objects with the right method (I'll let you look this up) can also be coerced.